# React-native - Failed to create provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I would like to run app on my physical device, but i have these errors.

- No profiles for 'org.reactjs.native.example.weekdays' were found

  - The app ID "org.reactjs.native.example.weekdays" cannot be registered to your development team.

Something wrong with bundles?!(org.reactjs.native.example.APPNAME) I'm a beginner.
Iphone 7 virtual device is working.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdLfS.png)

What should i do?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the solution to my issue that's similar to this one:

> Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

- Your bundle identifier is already in use by other developers I guess, so just change your **bundle identifier in the Identify tab** right above your **Signing tab** to another one:
- For example:
  Bundle Identifier: org.react.native.example.MyAwesomeWeekdaysIn2099

Comment: Hey @Mr.Dang, I just want to test push notification in my simulator but i just face the same error as he asking and i rewrite the bundle identifier but i got this error https://i.imgur.com/kbZtZwE.png

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an app provisioning profile, log in to Xcode, set bundle ID and set the team. It's all [documented here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile.html).