# Unable to build my new react-native project in xcode - getting profile provisioning error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have create a new react native project and opened it in xcode. When I run the application I get the error message that "No profiles for 'org.reactjs.native.example.testprovi' were found". The screen is attached. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I searched for the problem and found the answer to [it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54159210/11212074)

> Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

- Your bundle identifier is already in use by other developers I guess,
  so just change your bundle identifier in the Identify tab right above
  your Signing tab to another one:
- For example: Bundle Identifier:
  org.react.native.example.testprovi222

Comment: I created a new project and there are no other developers using this bundle identifier! I don’t know how to create a new provisioning profile?! Isn’t it because i am not using a paid apple developer account?

Comment: you need try this: Xcode => Preference => accounts => check your appleid and  If you don't have an Apple ID, press the plus button to register. => If you have an Apple ID,  press the Manage Certificates button to Development Certificates